# how to i connect my databse from oracle using this code in apex

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle-apex

I am using apex 4.0 and built a report in a region using a pre-made report, HTML, jQuery JavaScript and CSS, and I want to retrieve data from my Oracle database.

How can I retrieve data in this code from my Oracle database?

```
 <a class="offline-button" href="../index.html">Back</a>
 <script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#people.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div id="example" class="k-content">
        <div id="clientsDb">

            <div id="grid" style="height: 380px"></div>

        </div>

        <style scoped>
            #clientsDb {
                width: 692px;
                height: 413px;
                margin: 30px auto;
                padding: 51px 4px 0 4px;
                background: url(#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#clientsDb.png) no-repeat 0 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: createRandomData(50),
                        pageSize: 10
                    },
                    groupable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: true
                    },
                    columns: [ {
                            field: "FirstName",
                            width: 90,
                            title: "First Name"
                        } , {
                            field: "LastName",
                            width: 90,
                            title: "Last Name"
                        } , {
                            width: 100,
                            field: "City"
                        } , {
                            field: "Title"
                        } , {
                            field: "BirthDate",
                            title: "Birth Date",
                            template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"dd MMMM yyyy") #'
                        } , {
                            width: 50,
                            field: "Age"
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you know apex? If this code excerpt is HTML you put in a region, it will still be wrapped in form tags. The code also contains "kendoGrid". I didn't know that so i looked it up: if you intend to use this you should definitely mention this in your post as this is probably key. From those docs the solution you aim to achieve seems to be rather complex: you'll need web services or at the least ajax processes, with the ability to handle things such as paging. Clarify what you require and any pitfalls there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a different ways you can do this but since there is low information in your post, I will mostly try to answer your question which is "How Can you retrive data from an Oracle Database"

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1" type="text/javascript">

function getYourDataTableList (narrowText, empSelect) //getYourDataTableList should be the table you would like to retrive

{  

  var empSelectObj = document.getElementFirstName(FirstName);

  var ajaxRequest = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,'APPLICATION_PROCESS=getYourDataTableList ,0);

  ajaxRequest.add('P1_FirstName_NARROW',narrowText.value);

  ajaxResult = ajaxRequest.get();

  if(ajaxResult)

    {   

      empSelectObj.options.length = 0;

      var empArray = ajaxResult.split("~empsep~");

       for(var i=0; i < empArray.length; i++) {

        var colArray = empArray[i].split("~colsep~");

        empSelectObj.options[i] = new Option(colArray[1], colArray[0]);

      }

    }

    else

    {

      empSelectObj.options.length = 0;

    }

  ajaxRequest = null;   

}  

 </script>
```

-- The code is not tester nor will it be fully functional I recommend that you follow this example
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_html_db_apex_ajax_application_express.htm

Consider also that if you are using iFrame you might have this problem:(If the iframe src is a different server to your visualforce page, the browser won't allow javascript to access the contents as that would be considered a cross site scripting attack.)

**Source**:
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/How-we-get-the-iframe-data-in-apex-page-using-javascript/td-p/446781